# pandas group by sum of column size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have multiple huge tsv files which I'm trying to process using pandas. I want to group by 'col3' and 'col5'. I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep = "\t")
g1 = df.groupby(['col3', 'col5']).size()
```

It works fine so far and prints an output like this:

```
yes AB12 1
    FG14 1
no  nn18 1
    pp76 1
```

I want my output to be like:

```
yes 2
no  2
```

I'd like to be able to aggregate the output from multiple files, i.e., to be able to group by these two columns in all the files at once and print one common output with total number of occurrences of 'yes' or 'no' or whatever that attribute could be.

PS- Say I have duplicates in col3 for a given value in col5., I'd like them to be merged into one and not counted twice. In other words, if AB12 has two rows and both the rows have yes in col5, I'd like the script to count it as one and not two.

UPDATE:

I got the duplicates removed by doing:

```
g2 = df.drop_duplicates(['col3', 'col5'])
g3 = g2.groupby(['col3', 'col5']).size().sum(level=0)
print g3
```

I'd now like to use groupby on multiple files at once. And if a file doesn't have one of these columns, it should be skipped and we should go to the next file.

Comment: Isn't that just `df.groupby(['col3']).size()`?

Comment: @EdChum No. That way, it doesn't merge any possible duplicates in col5.

Comment: @EdChum Looks like I'm wrong, grouping by two cols is not eliminating duplicates. Please find the edited question.

Comment: Sorry but if you have another question please post another question, don't keep expanding your requirements

Comment: @EdChum I have posted it in my original question itself (not in the later expansions) that I need to do it on multiple files. Anything below Update is my expanded part. I can create another question if you think this isn't the way I should be doing it. I'm sorry.

Comment: I think so because that is a slightly different question, also SO is not a forum it's a Q+A site so your question should be for a specific problem

Comment: @EdChum Posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287943/pandas-groupby-for-multiple-data-frames-files-at-once. Also edited the title of this question so people know what it is about. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from ajcr's answer and additional line, I was able to remove the duplicates based on two columns by doing

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep = "\t")
g2 = df.drop_duplicates(['col3', 'col5'])
g3 = g2.groupby(['col3', 'col5']).size().sum(level=0)
print g3
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum()` accepts a `level` parameter, so you could write

```
df.groupby(['col3', 'col5']).size().sum(level=0)
```

in order to sum the group sizes for the first level of your MultiIndex ('col3' here). For instance:

```
>>> df
          a    
yes AB12  1
    FG14  2
no  nn18  3
    pp76  1

>>> df.sum(level=0)
     a    
no   4
yes  3
```